# is holes/gaps in postgresql sequences detrimental to performance?

Tags: database, postgresql, sequence

I implemented a system that leads to a lot of holes in Postgresql generated sequence values. I just wanted to ask if this can cause some reduction in performance?

If possible please include a reference where I can do further reading thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry. There won't be any influence on performance.

The main reason is that numbers (integer, bigint) are stored with a fixed amount of storage. So there is no differenc in storage or runtime overhead whether an ID holds the value 42 or 38643874638

Also: holes in sequences can not be avoided. As a primary key is just "some value" they don't matter either.

Storage requirements of integers: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-INT

Comment: As a_h_w_n_n says, no problem with gaps, but at some point you'll run out of numbers and there's no magic to avoid repeating previously-used numbers. Perhaps do some quick calculations to check whether int4 is large enough for you (sequences can support int8 just fine).

Comment: The only real issue is that if you use up your sequence real fast, and it's a regular 4 byte int, you can run out of values pretty quickly.  For this reason it's a good idea to use bigint / bigserial when you're not sure how fast they'll be used up.